# What are all the items shown in Picard's vault?

Tags: star-trek, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-picard

When Picard enters his personal vault in *Star Trek Picard* S01 E01 [Remembrance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Remembrance_(episode)), his vault is filled with memorabilia. While the model of the [USS Enterprise-E](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E)) is easily recognized (surprisingly no model of D), and the [USS Stargazer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Stargazer) somewhat less so, many of the other items are harder to place.

Can you identify the other objects in the room, and where they tie into previous Star Trek canon?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/every-star-trek-easter-egg-in-picards-vault/